# Subtleties between Java Period and Duration

Tags: java, time, duration

I'm not sure I'm getting the subtleties between Java `Period` and `Duration`.

When I read Oracle's [explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/period.html), it says that I can find out how many days since a birthday like this (using the example dates they used):

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate birthday = LocalDate.of(1960, Month.JANUARY, 1);
Period birthdayPeriod = Period.between(birthday, today);
int daysOld = birthdayPeriod.getDays();
```

But as even they point out, this doesn't take into account the time zone you were born in and the time zone you are in now. But this is a computer and we can be precise, right? So would I use a `Duration`?

```
ZoneId bornIn = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZonedDateTime born = ZonedDateTime.of(1960, Month.JANUARY.getValue(), 1, 2, 34, 56, 0, bornIn);
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
Duration duration = Duration.between(born, now);
long daysPassed = duration.toDays();
```

Now the actual times are accurate, but if I understand this correctly, the days might not correctly represent calendar days, e.g. with DST and such.

So what am I do to to get a precise answer based upon my time zone? The only thing I can think of is to go back to using `LocalDate`, but normalize the time zones first from the `ZonedDateTime` values, and then use a `Duration`.

```
ZoneId bornIn = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZonedDateTime born = ZonedDateTime.of(1960, Month.JANUARY.getValue(), 1, 2, 34, 56, 0, bornIn);
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
ZonedDateTime nowNormalized=now.withZoneSameInstant(born.getZone());
Period preciseBirthdayPeriod = Period.between(born.toLocalDate(), nowNormalized.toLocalDate());
int preciseDaysOld = preciseBirthdayPeriod.getDays();
```

But that seems really complicated just to get a precise answer.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a precise answer"? Suppose you were born at 12:30am two days ago, but yesterday there was a DST transition so the day was 25 hours long, and it's now 12:30am. You've been alive for 2 calendar days, but 49 hours. What "precise" answer do you want at that point? If you can specify *exactly* what answer you expect, it shouldn't be too hard to calculate it... but you do need to be really specific. (That's not even taking different zones into account.) Also, please use the preview to make sure your code is formatted appropriately when posting.

Comment: A Period is a span between calendar days, without regard to time of day.  If you want more precision than that, you should not be using Period.

Answer (score 18):

Your analysis regarding the Java-8-classes `Period` and `Duration` is more or less correct.

- The class `java.time.Period` is limited to calendar date precision.
- The class `java.time.Duration` only handles second (and nanosecond) precision but treats days always as equivalent to 24 hours = 86400 seconds.

**Normally it is completely sufficient to ignore clock precision or timezones when calculating the age of a person** because personal documents like passports don't document the exact time of day when someone was born. If so then the `Period`-class does its job (but please handle its methods like `getDays()` with care - see below).

**But you want more precision and describe the result in terms of local fields taking into account timezones.** Well, the first part (precision) is supported by `Duration`, but not the second part.

It is also not helpful to use `Period` because the exact time difference (which is ignored by `Period`) can impact the delta in days. And furthermore (just printing the output of your code):

```
    Period preciseBirthdayPeriod =
        Period.between(born.toLocalDate(), nowNormalized.toLocalDate());
    int preciseDaysOld = preciseBirthdayPeriod.getDays();
    System.out.println(preciseDaysOld); // 13
    System.out.println(preciseBirthdayPeriod); // P56Y11M13D
```

**As you can see, it is quite dangerous to use the method `preciseBirthdayPeriod.getDays()` in order to get the total delta in days. No, it is only a partial amount of the total delta. There are also 11 months and 56 years.** I think it is wise to also print the delta not only in days because then people can easier imagine how big the delta is (see the often seen use-case of printed durations in social media like "3 years, 2 months, and 4 days").

Obviously, you rather need a way to determine a duration including calendar units as well as clock units in a special timezone (in your example: the timezone where someone has been born). The bad thing about Java-8-time-library is: It does not support any combination of `Period` AND `Duration`. And importing the external library Threeten-Extra-class `Interval` will also not help because `long daysPassed = interval.toDuration().toDays();` will still ignore timezone effects (1 day == 24 hours) and is also not capable of printing the delta in other units like months etc.

**Summary:**

You have tried the `Period`-solution. The answer given by @swiedsw tried the `Duration`-based solution. Both approaches have disadvantages with respect to precision. You could try to combine both classes in a new class which implements `TemporalAmount` and realize the necessary time arithmetic yourself (not so trivial).

**Side note:**

I have myself already implemented in my time library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) what you look for, so it might be useful as inspiration for your own implementation. Example:

```
Timezone bornZone = Timezone.of(AMERICA.NEW_YORK);
Moment bornTime =
    PlainTimestamp.of(1960, net.time4j.Month.JANUARY.getValue(), 1, 22, 34, 56).in(
        bornZone
    );
Moment currentTime = Moment.nowInSystemTime();
MomentInterval interval = MomentInterval.between(bornTime, currentTime);

MachineTime<TimeUnit> mt = interval.getSimpleDuration();
System.out.println(mt); // 1797324427.356000000s [POSIX]

net.time4j.Duration<?> duration =
    interval.getNominalDuration(
        bornZone, // relevant if the moments are crossing a DST-boundary
        CalendarUnit.YEARS,
        CalendarUnit.MONTHS,
        CalendarUnit.DAYS,
        ClockUnit.HOURS,
        ClockUnit.MINUTES
    );

// P56Y11M12DT12H52M (12 days if the birth-time-of-day is after current clock time)
// If only days were specified above then the output would be: P20801D
System.out.println(duration);
System.out.println(duration.getPartialAmount(CalendarUnit.DAYS)); // 12
```

This example also demonstrates my general attitude that using units like months, days, hours etc. is not really exact in strict sense. The only strictly exact approach (from a scientific point of view) would be using the machine time in decimal seconds (best in SI-seconds, also possible in Time4J after the year 1972).

Comment: By “SI-seconds”, do you mean the same thing as [International Second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second#International_second) defined in Wikipedia?

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, exactly, SI-seconds as defined by International System of Units. In terms of given Time4J-example, it would require the expression [interval.getRealDuration()](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/MomentInterval.html#getRealDuration--), but as said not applicable for use-case of OP because OP also uses the year 1960 (before 1972).

Answer (score 5):

The JavaDoc of [`Period`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) states that it models:

> A date-based amount of time in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as '2 years, 3 months and 4 days'.

I understand it has no reference to points in time.

You might want to check [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) from project [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra) which models:

> an immutable interval of time between two instants.

The project website states the project “[...] is curated by the primary author of the Java 8 date and time library, Stephen Colebourne”.

You can retrieve a [`Duration`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html#toDuration) from an Interval by invoking `toDuration()` on it.

I shall transform your code to give an example:

```
ZoneId bornIn = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
ZonedDateTime born = ZonedDateTime.of(1960, Month.JANUARY.getValue(), 1, 2, 34, 56, 0, bornIn);
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
Interval interval = Interval.of(born.toInstant(), now.toInstant());
long daysPassed = interval.toDuration().toDays();
```

Comment: Good answer. In other words, an `Interval` is attached to the timeline while `Period` and `Duration` are not.

Answer (score 1):

The main distinction between the two classes is :

- that `java.time.Period` uses date-based values ( May 31, 2018)
- while `java.time.Duration` is more precise, it uses time-based values ( "2018-05-31T11:45:20.223Z" )

Answer (score 0):

`java.time.Period` is more friendly for human reading

- for example Period between A and B is 2 years 3 months 3 days

`java.time.Duration` is for a machine.